# What is the intuition behind Picard's existence and uniqueness theorem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

**Existence theorem**

*Let the right side $f(x,y)$ of the ODE in the initial value problem*
$$y' = f(x,y)$$
$$y(x_o) = y_o$$
*be continuous at all points $(x,y)$ in some rectangle*
$$R:|x-x_o|<a,|y-y_o|<b$$
*and* **bounded** *in R; that is, there is a number K such that*
$$|f(x,y)|\leq K \hspace{4em}\textit{ for all}\;(x,y)\;in\;R.$$
*Then the initial value problem has at least one solution $y(x)$ . This solution exists
at least for all $x$ in the subinterval $|x-x_o|<\alpha\:$ of the interval $|x-x_o|<a$;
here, $\alpha$ is the smaller of the two numbers $a$ and $\frac{b}{K}$.*

**Uniqueness Theorem**

*Let f and its partial derivative $f_y=\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$ be continuous for all $(x,y)$ in the rectangle
R and bounded, say,
$$|f(x,y)|\leq K$$
$$|f_y(x,y)|\leq M$$
$$\textit{for all }(x,y)\in\;  R.$$

Then the initial value problem has at most one solution $y(x).$ Thus, by Existence theorem, the problem has precisely one solution. This solution exist at least for all $x$ in that subinterval $|x-x_o|<\alpha$*

These are from Advanced Engineering Mathematics by **Erwin Kreyszig.**
What is the intuition behind these theorems and why we chose $\alpha=\min(a,\frac{b}{K})$?

Comment: $\alpha=\min(a,b/K)$ is chosen so that the solution is guaranteed not to leave the rectangle where $f$ is given to be continuous. Naturally $\alpha \leq a$ is required, but $\alpha \leq b/K$ is not necessarily optimal.